# How to calculate waiting time for customer based on previous customers's waiting time

Tags: statistics, future, prediction, time-estimation

Can anyone suggest a method to calculate customer waiting time for a restaurant based on previous waiting times. My system stores the waiting time of each customer and based on this values i want to predict the waiting time for next customer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't predict an exact figure.

But a simple statistical approach would be:

```
average( waiting_time ) + ( 2 * standard_deviation( waiting_time ) )
```

That is, take the average and add two standard deviations.

Assuming that wait time is normally distributed, the result from the above equation is the *maximum amount* of waiting time that approximately [95%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) of your customers would experience.

Comment: thnx for replying..
can you tell me how you figured out this statistic...i would like to dig deeper into the same.

Comment: Any common statistics textbook will do.

Comment: Note: For this purpose, you should be calculating SD with [Bessel's Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel's_correction) as an estimate of true population SD.

Answer (score 2):

A [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) is a stochastic process which counts the number of events and the time that these events occur in a given time interval. The time between each pair of consecutive events, for example, customer waiting time, has an [Exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).  From wiki:

> The exponential distribution occurs naturally when describing the lengths of the inter-arrival times in a homogeneous Poisson process.

## Prediction

Using maximum likelihood estimation, you can use the inverse sample mean to get the `rate parameter` of exponential distribution.

[image]

## Confidence Interval

From wiki:

> A simple and rapid method to calculate an approximate confidence interval for the estimation of λ is based on the application of the central limit theorem. This method provides a good approximation of the confidence interval limits, for samples containing at least 15 – 20 elements. Denoting by N the sample size, the upper and lower limits of the 95% confidence interval are given by:

[image]

For more details, see [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) and [Exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).